# How do I recursively delete all files or folders whose names match a pattern in Windows?

Tags: windows-7

For the file example, I would like to delete all files matching .+?[a-f0-9]{4}.html (i.e. any html file ending in a four digit hexadecimal).  So paged47c.html would be deleted, but page.html would remain.

For the folder example, I would like to delete all folders matching .+?[A-Z]+ (i.e. any folder containing a capital letter).  So some-folderSE93_89ds/ would be deleted, but some-folder/ would remain.

I don't work much with the command line, but I could probably get an example involving "del" to work for me.  Alternatively, is there a simple GUI program for Windows that would do this?

Answer (score 4):

I would say the easiest way, albeit not the direct route, is to do your specialized `dir` command (you can use /b and /s switched to make it *just* list the filename and to recurse directories) and redirect it to a file.  Open it in notepad (or insert your favorite editor), search and replace to add "del " to the beginning of the lines, save it off as mydel.bat, and execute.

So an example would be:

`dir /s /b *.html > mydel.bat
notepad mydel.bat
call mydel.bat`

Comment: How would I delete all files not named "test.txt"?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following line in powershell:

> `Get-ChildItem  -Recurse C:\| where { ! $_.PSIsContainer } | Where-Object {$_.Name -match ".+?[a-f0-9]{4}.html"}`

Is for the file case, for the folder case use:

> `Get-ChildItem  -Recurse C:\| Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer }| Where-Object {$_.Name -match ".+?[A-Z]+"}`

Store those both in variables, and then use `Remove-Item`

**Warning:** In my command, I am using the root `C:\` as the source location. If you do want to pipe it's output to `Remove-Item` and you are running this as administrator, its a bad idea. At the very least do one of the following:

1. Specifically exclude `Windows`
2. Using the `what-if` flag
3. Don't run as administrator (if the files that you are matching are not in a protected directory, it won't matter)
4. Don't run use `C:\` but rather from some safer place

Comment: This helped me, thanks.  I'd recommend changing the `C:` to `.`--I just ran it not realizing you pointed it to `C:`--good thing you didn't put the `Remove-Item` in there :)

Comment: @notfed, point well taken